# In react, object is seems to be as an empty object for using fetch

Tags: reactjs, javascript-objects

If I use a variable instead of using react state object inside a function is behaving weirdly for fetch. If i remove the const response..... and const data.... line things works just fine but If i use fetch function and use normal variable without using state this doesn't work. Why is that?

[Object is showing normal if i log it from inside the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRUKn.png)

[Object is also showing normal if i use const variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IEti.png)

[Object is showing like an empty object if i log it from outside the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3kl2.png)

But this code works just fine..

```
   const [services, setServices] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
    const API_URL = "http://localhost:8080/getServiceName/3";

    const loadData = async () => {
        const apiData = [];
        const response = await fetch(API_URL);
        const data = await response.json();

        data.services.map(service => (
            apiData.push(service.service_name)
        ));
        setServices(apiData);
    }
    loadData();
   }, [location])
```

And notice that i can add more value to a const variable(const dummyLocation{in image} and const apiData in code)!, How??

Comment: Please edit your question and describe specifically what did you get on each attempt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You yourself showing that it does have data in console.log , when you try to expand the Object. It is showing blank  in non-expanded view because console.log was synchronous and at the time of execution it did not contain any data. When asynchronous called get resolved , it filled dummyLocation with all the data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`loadData();` is asynchronous, so if you do

```
loadData()
console.log(dummyLocation)
```

then the `console.log` will happen before `loadData` completed.  You probably just want to do

```
loadData().then(() => console.log(dummyLocation))
```

As for the questions regarding why you can do:

```
const apiData = [];
// ...
apiData.push(service.service_name)
```

the reason is that `const` doesn't mean the variable can't change (per se), but instead that the variable will never be reassigned - you can't do:

```
const apiData = [];
apiData = [service.service_name];
```

because that is assigning a new array to it.

Comment: So when i use state it check if the value changed or not and it keeps the update so that's why i can go with state in this case?